# SQL error 1064 in simple cakePHP setup

Tags: sql, cakephp, tree

I am using the simplest controller and model as shown here:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1341/Basic-Usage

But when i go to `www.mysite.com/categories` 
the code that causes it is:

```
<?php
class CategoriesController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Categories';

    function index() {
        $this->data = $this->Category->generatetreelist(null, null, null, '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
        debug ($this->data); die;       
    }
}
?>
```

i get the following error:

```
Warning (512): SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'recover' at line 1 [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 684]
Code | Context

            $out = null;
            if ($error) {
                trigger_error('<span style="color:Red;text-align:left"><b>' . __('SQL Error:', true) . "</b> {$this->error}</span>", E_USER_WARNING);

$sql    =   "recover"
$error  =   "1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'recover' at line 1"
$out    =   null

DboSource::showQuery() - CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 684
DboSource::execute() - CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 266
DboSource::fetchAll() - CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 410
DboSource::query() - CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 364
Model::call__() - CORE/cake/libs/model/model.php, line 502
Overloadable::__call() - CORE/cake/libs/overloadable_php5.php, line 50
AppModel::recover() - [internal], line ??
CategoriesController::index() - APP/controllers/categories_controller.php, line 7
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 204
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 171
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 83

Query: recover

app/controllers/categories_controller.php (line 8)
```

I am totally confused, since I just copy-pasted from the original cakephp cookbook tutorial.

I have:
controllers/categories_controller.php
models/category_model.php
and the code is copy paste from the tutorial.

Any help?

Comment: Problem solved. Misnaming the model file. It Was: `category_model.php` Should have been: `category.php` **=(**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. Misnaming the model file. 
It Was: category_model.php 
Should have been: category.php =(

Comment: This happens to me once in a while, hah!

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you created the Category Model?
2. I am not sure but I belive you should tell the controller which model u intend to use by specifying:

   var $name = 'Categories';
   var $uses = array("Category");

   function index() {
           $this->data = $this->Category->generatetreelist(null, null, null, '   ');
           debug ($this->data); die;
       }

Comment: When following conventions (as is the case), there is no need to specify the model