# Controller Unit Test fails with SQLSTATE[42000] error

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I want to unit test a controller action and have some problem toio excecute it.
The Error i got is the following:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'questionExists'
>   at line 1

The Method:

> questionExists

is defined inside the Question Model.

My test function looks like this:

```
public function testView() {
        $result = $this->testAction('/questions/questions/view/1', array('return' => 'vars'));
    }
```

The Controller action i want to test looks like this:

public function view($id = null) {

```
    if (!$this->Question->questionExists($id, 'id_virtual')) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid question'));
    }
    $options = array('conditions' => array('Question.id_virtual' => $id));
    $this->set('question', $this->Question->find('first', $options));
}
```

So this is very confusing to me.
Can anybody point me to the right direction ?

Comment: You can check the class of your Question object (`debug(get_class($$this->Question));` - it will be `AppModel`) to confirm burzum's answer. The typical reason is a typo in the filename.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL error 1064 in simple cakePHP setup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613094/sql-error-1064-in-simple-cakephp-setup)

Comment: i think this is not a possible duplicate. I just got the error in unit tests. The appmis running perfectly

Comment: All errors of this kind have the same cause: the model instance does not implement the called method. In your case there is probably a reference to the model `Question` (that would be a AppModel instance) which is found in some cases before the model `Question.Question`. When you find the cause (comments so far only describe a workaround) please add it as an answer =).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model class is not found, CakePHP creates an instance on the fly for that table but this is not more than the basic Model class. When the code is then called it tries to call that method on an instance that is not your Question model in your app. You'll have to figure out what that happens.

Comment: The problem is very curious. After adding this Line 
`public $uses = array('Questions.Question');`
in my QuestionsController the test runs perfectly. But now im very confused about that. I never needed to add this line before.

Comment: I also have noticed that if im using 
`$this->autoMock = false; `
everything works fine too.

Comment: In this case I guess that if autoMock is true you get your models mocked. So you would have to work with expectations for the model calls. Just check if the object is a mock object and if it is use expects() for it.